# $f(n) = 2f(n-1) -f(n-2) + 1$ find closed form by repeated substitution

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$f(0)=a$$
$$f(1)=b$$

$$f(n) = 2f(n-1) -f(n-2) + 1$$
How can I begin repeated substitution with this? I'm confused because there are two $f$ terms not sure how to sub for both of them.

Comment: $f(n) - f(n-1) = g(n)$, then $g(n) = g(n-1) + 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some computations $$f(2) = 2f(1)-f(0)+1 = 2b-a+1,$$ $$f(3) = 2f(2)-f(1)+1 = 4b-2a+2-b+1 = 3b-2a+3,$$ $$f(4) = 2f(3)-f(2)+1 = 6b-4a+6-2b+a-1+1 = 4b-3a+6,$$ you can conjecture that $$f(n) = nb-(n-1)a+ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ and prove this by induction.

Answer (score 2):

I like to express recursions of this type by matrix-expressions, such that with a initial vector $[1,a,b]$ we get by the transfer matrix $M$ the vector $[1,b,c]$ where $b$ and $c$ are defined by one step of the recursion.
For your problem $$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&1 \\\ 0&0&-1 \\\ 0&1&2 \end{bmatrix}$$
and then 
$$ [1,a_1,a_2] \cdot M^h = [1,a_h,a_{h+1}] \tag 0 $$
where $h$ is then the iteration-"height".

Often [diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) of the transfermatrix $M$ allow then the direct expression of the matrixpower $M^h$ in a formula with $h$ kept indeterminate.

---

In your case I don't find a diagonalization for $M$ but a ["similarity"-transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) (or "[Schur-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition)") of $M$ into $D$ such that with the orthogonal ("rotation"-) matrix $T$ and a triangular matrix $D$
$$ M = T^\tau \cdot D \cdot T  \tag 1$$
such that 
$$ M^h = T^\tau \cdot D^h \cdot T   \tag 2 $$
Here the superpostfix $\tau$ at matrixname $T$ means "transpose" but, because $T$ is constructed to be orthogonal, means also the inverse and thus we have indeed a "similarity" transformation.

Here $D$ has the identity-diagonal and $D^h = \exp(h \cdot \log(D))$ can be given in exact polynomial terms of $h$.
Let's denote $q = \sqrt {0.5}$ then I found that a valid solution for $T$ is
$$ T= \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1 \\\ q&-q&0 \\\ q&q&0 \end{bmatrix}   \tag 3
$$
then
$$ D= T^\tau \cdot M \cdot T=
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\\ 2&1&0 \\\ q&q&1 \end{bmatrix}   \tag 4$$
The matrix-logarithm of $D$ is then
$$ \Lambda= \log(D)= 
\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0 \\\ 2&0&0 \\\ 0&q&0 \end{bmatrix}   \tag 5$$
and $D^h$ has then the simple form
$$  D^h = \exp(h \cdot \Lambda) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\\ 2h&1&0 \\\ q \cdot h^2&q \cdot h&1 \end{bmatrix}    \tag 6
$$
and $M^h$ is then
$$M^h = T \cdot D^h \cdot T^\tau =
\begin{bmatrix} 1& \frac12 h(h-1)& \frac 12 h(h+1) \\\ 0&1-h&-h \\\ 0& h&h+1 \end{bmatrix}   \tag 7$$
and thus using eq $(0)$
$$   [1, a_1, a_2] \cdot M^h = [1, a_h, a_{h+1}] \\\
    a_{h+1}= \left([1,a_1,a_2] \cdot M^h\right)  [3] $$
we get
$$ a_{h+1} = \frac12h(h+1) -h\cdot a_1 + (h+1) a_2   \tag 8$$

---

***Remarks:***

- the equation (5) can exactly be determined by the mercatorseries for $(D-I)$ because $D-I$ is nilpotent and the series collapses to a finite sum.
- the equation (6) can exactly be determined by the common exponential-series on $ h\cdot \Lambda$ because $ h\cdot \Lambda$ is nilpotent and the exponential series collapses to a finite sum.
- In light of some other questions of the same type but where the triangular matrix **D** has entries $\ne 1$ in the diagonal it might be even better, more general and thus ***the "canonical"*** solution, to use the ***Jordan-decomposition*** $M=S \cdot J \cdot S^{-1}$ instead where the matrix **J** has an even simpler form than **D** and the matrix-log and -exponential can as easy be computed as with the diagonalization in the diagonalizable cases. Unfortunately, the Jordan-decomposition is tedious even with $3\times3$-matrices (but can for instance be [called from Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordanform%20%7B%7B1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C2%7D%7D)) so I proposed the triangular decomposition-version here.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
f(n)-2f(n-1)+f(n-2)=1
$$
if we let
$$
g(n)=f(n)-\frac{n^2}2
$$
we get
$$
g(n)-2g(n-1)+g(n-2)=0
$$
the solution to which is $g(n)=cn+d$, since the characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^2$. Thus, because $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=b$,
$$
f(n)=\frac{n^2-n}2+(b-a)n+a
$$

Answer (score 1):

A standard way to do this is through generating function.

The generating function of $f(n)$ is
$$
g(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} f(n)z^n
$$
Multiply both sides of the recursion by $z^{n}$ gives
$$
z^{n}f(n+2) = 2 z^{n} f(n+1) - z^{n}f(n) + z^n
$$
Sum over $n \ge 0$ and we get
$$
\frac{-a-b z+g(z)}{z^2}=\frac{2 (g(z)-a)}{z}-g(z)+\frac{1}{1-z}
$$
Solving this gives
$$
g(z)=\frac{-2 a z^2+3 a z-a+b z^2-b z-z^2}{(z-1)^3}
$$
Now you can get the coefficient of $g(z)$ by applying a binomial expansion to $(z-1)^{-3}$.

Comment: Thank you again, I deleted my question there since you answer it fully.